# getting ParseException when processing months and days

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

I am trying to parse the following date: `10:00 AM (UTC-08:00) on Sep 3, 2015` using SimpleDateFormat.

The furthest I got was:

```
message = "10:00 AM UTC-08:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a z");
sdf.parse(message);
```

once I added the months and the days in the month I got the following exception:
(I tried to remove the brackets and the 'on' but I would love to get find a solution that elegantly deal with that)

```
message = "10:00 AM UTC-08:00 on Sep 3";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a z MMM d");
result = {java.text.ParseException@9787}Method threw 'java.text.ParseException' exception.
errorOffset = 12
detailMessage = "Unparseable date: "10:00 AM UTC-08:00 Jul""
```

Would love to know what I am missing.

Comment: `once I added the months and the days in the month`, can you show what you did?

Comment: what format you have used for parsing "10:00 AM UTC-08:00 Jul"

Comment: @BasilBourque I showed my full input then I showed how far I got with out getting an exception. The goal is to parse the string above and get a date.

Comment: @Zar I have update the Q. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use your input like : Jul 10:00 AM UTC-08:00

and Format like : MMM HH:mm a z

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that the timezone must be at the end.

These all work:

```
String message = "10:00 AM UTC-08:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a z");

String message = "Jul";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");

String message = "10:00 AM Jul UTC-08:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a MMM z");

String message = "UTC-08:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z");
```

Yet these do not:

```
String message = "10:00 AM UTC-08:00 Jul";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a z MMM");

String message = "UTC-08:00 10:00 AM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z HH:mm a");
```

In addition, all of the pattern examples I saw had the timezone at the end. But I could not find any documentation explicitly stating this, so anyone reading this please share if you know anything else.